# How to specify separately the path of the java file and the tokens file generated by Antlr?

Tags: java, maven, antlr, antlr4

I`m attempting to use antlr4 in my project to parse files in custom format. But when I use antlr4 maven plugin, I cannot find a parameter to set separately the path of tokens file and java file, as it can only set a common path.

Here`s the configuration of antlr4 maven plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>antlr</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>antlr4</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>compile</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
        <libDirectory>src/main/antlr4/imports</libDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/antlr4</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        <listener>true</listener>
        <visitor>true</visitor>
        <treatWarningsAsErrors>true</treatWarningsAsErrors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The grammar file `test.g4` is in <sourceDirectory>/relativePath(`src/main/antlr4/org/trance233/antlr/`).

The `.tokens` file is in <outputDirectory>(`src/main/java/`), the `.java` file is in <sourceDirectory>/relativePath(`src/main/java/org/trance233/antlr/`).

Is there any way that can set the path separately? Such as the `.tokens` file above is put in `src/main/resources`, and the `.java` file is put in `src/main/java/org/trance233/antlr/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A configuration for antlr4 is usually very simple like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>antlr4</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <visitor>true</visitor>
          <listener>false</listener>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This assumes you have your grammar file in `src/main/antlr4/<package>/test.g4` (default location). There is no need to configure such things etc. because by conventions the generated class will be available in `target/generated-sources/antlr4/`. Exactly in this directory you will find the `*.tokens` files. The imports directory is defined by default as `src/main/antl4/imports`. The default configuration for the [antlr4-maven-plugin](https://www.antlr.org/api/maven-plugin/latest/antlr4-mojo.html) defines some very useful defaults and it is strongly recommended to follow those conventions.

I strongly recommmend **NOT** to configure the `<outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>` because that will generate code in your `src/` directory tree which can cause issues with your versions control system.

BTW: Binding the code generation to the phase `compile` is very bad because the code generation should be done before the compile phase. The `generate-sources` phase is exactly intended for such cases. This phase is used by default by the antlr4-maven-plugin.

Comment: Thanks! So what I should do is use as mush as possible default configuration and not set 'compile' phase. Then set `generated-sources` to generated-sources-folder(I`m using IDEA). Is it okay?

Comment: Yes. Follow conventions over configuration paradigm. Also don't set the phase explicitly because the plugin already does that correrctly (and knows best where to bind to the life cycle phase)..(For details: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way that can set the path separately?

No.

But you can remove the `.tokens` file: it is not needed at runtime for your generated parser classes.